# Why is feature not defined python

Tags: python

First off I would like to say im a total noob when it comes to code. Im in school for a CS Degree and python is my first language. I'm supposed to create a zoo class that prints out information based on the arguments I provided. for some reason I cant get this to compile and im not even sure im doing anything correctly. my teacher teacher is on vacation so the sub doest really help. thanks guys

```
import random
question = 'y'

while question == 'y':
    #animals we want are lion, turtle, kangaroo,
    kind=['lion','turtle', 'kangaroo', 'flamingo', 'pinguin', 'bear']
    animalType= random.choice (kind)
    legs= str(random.randint(0,4))
    age= str(random.randint(1,70))


    class Parent:
        """ superclass for a Zoo of animals """

        def __init__(self, kind, legs, age):
            self.animalType = animalType
            self.legs = legs
            self.age = age




        def getanimal (self):
            return self.animalType
        def getlegs (self):
            return self.legs
        def getage (self):
            return self.age



        def __str__(self):
            output = 'Kind of Animal {}, Number of legs {}, Age {} '.format(self.animalType, self.legs, self.age)

            return output

        def makeNoise(self):
            return None

    class Cub(Parent):
        """subclass of parent"""
        feature='playful'

        def __init__(kid, animalType, legs, age, feature="playful"):
            super(Parent).__init__(animalType, legs, age)
            kid.feature = feature

        def getplayful (kid):
            return kid.feature

        def __str__(kid,):
            parentOutput = super(Parent).__str__()
            output = 'cub traits {} {}'.format(
                                            parentOutput, kid.feature)
            return output

        def makeNoise(kid):
            if make_Noise is True:
                print('ROAR')
            print()

    class babyTurtle (Parent):
        """subclass of parent"""
        slow= "slow"
        def __init__(kid, animalType, legs, age, feature = 'slow'):
            super(Parent).__init__(animalType, legs, age)
            kid.feature = feature

        def getslow (kid):
            return kid.feature

        def __str__(kid):
            parentOutput = super(Parent).__str__()
            output = 'babyTurtle traits {} {}'.format(
                                            parentOutput, kid.feature)
            return output

        def makeNoise(kid):
            if make_Noise is True:
                print('do baby turtles even make noise?')
            print('')

    class marsupial(Parent):
        """subclass of Parent"""

        def __init__(kid, legs, age, animalType, feature='kanga jack is gonna kick you out'):
            super(Parent).__init__(animalType, legs, age)
            kid.feature = feature

        def getkanga (kid):
            return kid.feature

        def __str__(kid):
            parentOutput = super(Parent).__str__()
            output = 'kanga traits {} {} '.format(
                                            parentOutput, self.kanga)
            return output

        def makeNoise(kid):
            if make_Noise is True:
                print('the name is Jack')
            print('')


    animal1 = Parent(kind, legs, age)
    Zoo=[]
    Zoo.append(animal1)

    answer = input("add another animal y/n: ")
    if answer == question:
        question = 'y'
    elif answer == 'n':
        kid1= Cub(kind, legs, age, feature)
        kid2= babyturtle(kind, legs, age, feature)
        kid3= marsupial(kind, legs, age, feature)
        print (Zoo)
        print (kid1, True.makeNoise)
        print (kid2, True.makeNoise)
        print (kid3, True.makeNoise)
        question = 'n'
    else:
        print("error")
```

Comment: Nice click-baity title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're playing fast and loose with your `__init__()` definitions, and then you're missing something when calling them.

If you want to create various animal objects in a standard fashion, you have to define them in a standard fashion. Using `kid, animalType, legs, age, feature` but `kid, legs, age, animalType, feature` will not allow you to do that (and I recommend using the standard `self` to refer to instances of an object, rather than `kid`).

When you try to create an animal, you're providing it with its type, number of legs, and age, but you never told the constructor what `feature` was. The others are defined near the top of the program (I recommend taking the class definitions out of the loop, by the way), but `feature` is nowhere to be found. Define it in some way, or leave out the reference to `feature` (i.e., use something like `kid1= Cub(kind, legs, age)`) entirely to fall to the default value.